# How do I generate a yup scheme on server side and send it to browser for use?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, yup

I have got a project with forms. The only 1 thing I want to do, is to generate forms dynamically, depending on theme scheme, returned by server side.

For schema generating I use `yup`. Is there any methods inside `yup` that could convert generated scheme to JSON on server side and convert from JSON to Scheme object in browser?